# Phantom Images showing in image capture

Tags: iphone, photos, graphics, image-capture

macbook pro catalina 10.15.7, iphone 7 ios 14.2. Here is a screen of some pictures in the camera roll that were taken with the phone.
[image: pictures in camera roll]

When i connect the phone to the mac book pro and open image capture, i get duplicates and there is an "E" added to the file name and the duplicates files seem to be smaller in size.  Question - what causes these duplicates and why arent they showing in the camera roll on the phone?
[image: E duplicates]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**E photos are edited.**

The text you added to the photo creates an IMG_Exxxx.JPG file with the changes you made.

The original is preserved as IMG_xxxx.JPG which can be reverted to using the Revert button in the Photos app when editing a photo.

Comment: so the ones w/ the "E" in the file name are not visable in the camera roll but somewhere available in case reverted to? I did have more photos in the camera roll that also showed in image capture w/ the "E".  Upon investigation i presumed possibly what you mention and also that some of the others had no text but were edited before emailing or sending via imessage.  So guess "E" is added and duplicate hidden file for reverting when edited....  tks

Comment: @Stumped Almost, the E photos are the ones visible if they exist. The original is always without E, then if you edit the photo a new file with an E is created.

Comment: tks.  must be a new change or something in finder or better yet, image capture...  as I never before now have noticed 2 sets of photos until now when plugging in the phone and using image capture - even before when I had edited photos.  appreciate it.